# Clone The First Letter Of Title

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clone the first letter of each blog title, and add it to the beginning of the blog title. In other words, I want each Blog title to have duplicate first letter so I can use CSS `.post-title:first-letter` to style it as a background.

HTML:

```
<h3 class="post-title">Post Title</h3>
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery('.post-title').each(function(){
  var letter_clone = "if(jQuery(this).text().charAt(0)";
  $(this).prepend('+ letter_clone +');
})
```

Comment: You're trying to prepend a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were sort of on the right track. I believe this should achieve the desired handling? (duplicates the first letter)

```js
jQuery('.post-title').each(function(){
  var letter_clone = jQuery(this).text().charAt(0);
  $(this).prepend(letter_clone);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="post-title">Post Title</h3>
```